# What's the function of "mismo" in this sentence?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

What's the exact function of "mismo" in the following sentence?

For example:

> Se llevó a cabo la ceremonia y el mismo presidente le entregó la medalla al soldado.

I'm a native speaker and I think it is to make an emphasis of the next word. I just want to get this clarified. Here "mismo" is not about the "same thing" because there is another usage where it could be used as this:

> Laura y yo tenemos los mismos gustos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function of *mismo* in that type of sentence is described by the "Diccionario panhispánico de dudas" (DPHD) as follows:

> 2.- A menudo se emplea como mero refuerzo enfático y puede ir antepuesto o pospuesto al sustantivo, a veces en forma diminutiva (mismito) o superlativa (mismísimo): «Mis sorpresas comenzaron en la puerta misma del Club Alemán de la ciudad» (Edwards Anfitrión [Chile 1987]); «Me dejó con la espina clavada en el mismito centro de mi corazón» (LpzPáez Herlinda [Méx. 1993]); «Se atrevió a dar el paso de telefonearlo a la mismísima casa de su amante» (Vergés Cenizas [R. Dom. 1980]). Puede seguir a un pronombre personal: «Nosotros mismos nos condenamos al nacer» (Britton Siglo [Pan. 1995]); su empleo es obligatorio tras un pronombre tónico que, a su vez, refuerza al reflexivo átono correspondiente: «Muchas veces usted no se cuida a sí mismo» (Sophia Arte [EE. UU. 1996]); aquí no sería posible *usted no se cuida a sí; sin embargo, en ausencia del pronombre átono, no es obligatorio añadir el refuerzo mismo: «Gracias al instinto de supervivencia cada uno cuida de sí» (GmzPérez Abc [Esp. 1994]).

This means that its function is to emphasize the substantive it precedes or follows. In some cases it may be transformed to its diminutive or augmentative form ("*mismito*" or "*mismísimo*"):

> *En el discurso final fue el **mismísimo** presidente quien agradeció la ayuda prestada por todos sus colaboradores*.
>
> →  During the final speech was the **very** president who gave thanks to his collaborators for their help.

It is important to note that in the first example given by the DPHD above, the word *mismo* follows the substantive it modifies:

> *Mis sorpresas comenzaron en la puerta **misma** del Club Alemán de la ciudad*
>
> →  My surprises began at the very entrance of the city's German Club.

that could be said as well:

> *Mis sorpresas comenzaron en la **mismísima** puerta del Club Alemán de la ciudad*.

Using *mismo* after the substantive it modifies is something (I think) that not always sounds good. I could recommend using it before the substantive when not really sure.

Answer (score 10):

In that sentence, "mismo" could be translated as "very" or "himself":

> The ceremony was carried out and the very president handed the medal
>   to the soldier.

or

> The ceremony was carried out and the president himself handed the medal
>   to the soldier.

As you guessed, it is an emphatic; it means that it was the president and no other person who did that.

Comment: I like "himself" better than "very." "Very sounded sort of right but sort of funny to my ear, so I looked it up in the Oxford dictionary (which I like because it includes usage examples).  (See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/very.)  The relevant definition says: real, genuine, proper, true, rightly so called.  That fits.  But interestingly, it gave this definition as *archaic*.  Maybe that's why I sounded a little weird to my ear.